# Spring Security + SAML 2.0 Configuration --> WebServerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, saml-2.0

Trying to configure Spring Security + Saml 2.0 for our app. Without the Spring Security config the app runs fine. As soon as we activate Spring Security we get a Tomcat exception as follows:

```
2023-01-12 19:53:21.191  INFO 31028 --- [  restartedMain] com.atos.AerApp                          : Starting AerApp using Java 17.0.5 on LAPTOP-FRSNQQSJ with PID 31028 (C:\Projects local\AER-Backend\backend\build\classes\java\main started by a882102 in C:\Projects local\AER-Backend\backend)
2023-01-12 19:53:21.192  INFO 31028 --- [  restartedMain] com.atos.AerApp                          : No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
2023-01-12 19:53:21.223  INFO 31028 --- [  restartedMain] .e.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor : Devtools property defaults active! Set 'spring.devtools.add-properties' to 'false' to disable
2023-01-12 19:53:21.223  INFO 31028 --- [  restartedMain] .e.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor : For additional web related logging consider setting the 'logging.level.web' property to 'DEBUG'
2023-01-12 19:53:21.776  INFO 31028 --- [  restartedMain] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2023-01-12 19:53:21.813  INFO 31028 --- [  restartedMain] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 32 ms. Found 3 JPA repository interfaces.
2023-01-12 19:53:22.254  INFO 31028 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2023-01-12 19:53:22.260  INFO 31028 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2023-01-12 19:53:22.260  INFO 31028 --- [  restartedMain] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.70]
2023-01-12 19:53:22.325  INFO 31028 --- [  restartedMain] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2023-01-12 19:53:22.325  INFO 31028 --- [  restartedMain] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1102 ms
2023-01-12 19:53:22.334 ERROR 31028 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatStarter  : Error starting Tomcat context. Exception: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException. Message: Error creating bean with name 'metadata' defined in class path resource [com/atos/config/SecurityConfig.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'metadata' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'relyingPartyRegistrationResolver' defined in class path resource [com/atos/config/SecurityConfig.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'relyingPartyRegistrationResolver' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'repository' defined in class path resource [com/atos/config/SecurityConfig.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.security.saml2.provider.service.registration.RelyingPartyRegistrationRepository]: Factory method 'repository' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "java.net.URL.getFile()" because the return value of "java.lang.ClassLoader.getResource(String)" is null
2023-01-12 19:53:22.362  INFO 31028 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2023-01-12 19:53:22.368  WARN 31028 --- [  restartedMain] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start web server; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat
2023-01-12 19:53:22.373  INFO 31028 --- [  restartedMain] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2023-01-12 19:53:22.389 ERROR 31028 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start web server; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:165) ~[spring-boot-2.7.7.jar:2.7.7]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:577) ~[spring-context-5.3.24.jar:5.3.24]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:147) ~[spring-boot-2.7.7.jar:2.7.7]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:731) ~[spring-boot-2.7.7.jar:2.7.7]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:408) ~[spring-boot-2.7.7.jar:2.7.7]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:307) ~[spring-boot-2.7.7.jar:2.7.7]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1303) ~[spring-boot-2.7.7.jar:2.7.7]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1292) ~[spring-boot-2.7.7.jar:2.7.7]
    at com.atos.AerApp.main(AerApp.java:18) ~[main/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) ~[spring-boot-devtools-2.7.7.jar:2.7.7]
Caused by: org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.initialize(TomcatWebServer.java:142) ~[spring-boot-2.7.7.jar:2.7.7]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.<init>(TomcatWebServer.java:104) ~[spring-boot-2.7.7.jar:2.7.7]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getTomcatWebServer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:479) ~[spring-boot-2.7.7.jar:2.7.7]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getWebServer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:211) ~[spring-boot-2.7.7.jar:2.7.7]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.createWebServer(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:184) ~[spring-boot-2.7.7.jar:2.7.7]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:162) ~[spring-boot-2.7.7.jar:2.7.7]
    ... 13 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'metadata' defined in class path resource [com/atos/config/SecurityConfig.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'metadata' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'relyingPartyRegistrationResolver' defined in class path resource [com/atos/config/SecurityConfig.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'relyingPartyRegistrationResolver' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'repository' defined in class path resource [com/atos/config/SecurityConfig.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.security.saml2.provider.service.registration.RelyingPartyRegistrationRepository]: Factory method 'repository' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "java.net.URL.getFile()" because the return value of "java.lang.ClassLoader.getResource(String)" is null
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:800) ~[spring-beans-5.3.24.jar:5.3.24]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:541) ~[spring-beans-5.3.24.jar:5.3.24]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1352) ~[spring-beans-5.3.24.jar:5.3.24]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1195) ~[spring-beans-5.3.24.jar:5.3.24]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:582) ~[spring-beans-5.3.24.jar:5.3.24]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.24.jar:5.3.24]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.24.jar:5.3.24]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.24.jar:5.3.24]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.24.jar:5.3.24]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:213) ~[spring-beans-5.3.24.jar:5.3.24]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletContextInitializerBeans.getOrderedBeansOfType(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:212) ~[spring-boot-2.7.7.jar:2.7.7]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletContextInitializerBeans.getOrderedBeansOfType(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:203) ~[spring-boot-2.7.7.jar:2.7.7]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletContextInitializerBeans.addServletContextInitializerBeans(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:97) ~[spring-boot-2.7.7.jar:2.7.7]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletContextInitializerBeans.<init>(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:86) ~[spring-boot-2.7.7.jar:2.7.7]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.getServletContextInitializerBeans(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:262) ~[spring-boot-2.7.7.jar:2.7.7]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.selfInitialize(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:236) ~[spring-boot-2.7.7.jar:2.7.7]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatStarter.onStartup(TomcatStarter.java:53) ~[spring-boot-2.7.7.jar:2.7.7]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5211) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.70.jar:9.0.70]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.70.jar:9.0.70]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1393) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.70.jar:9.0.70]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1383) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.70.jar:9.0.70]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.70.jar:9.0.70]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:145) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:916) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.70.jar:9.0.70]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:835) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.70.jar:9.0.70]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.70.jar:9.0.70]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1393) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.70.jar:9.0.70]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1383) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.70.jar:9.0.70]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.70.jar:9.0.70]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:145) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:916) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.70.jar:9.0.70]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:265) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.70.jar:9.0.70]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.70.jar:9.0.70]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:430) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.70.jar:9.0.70]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.70.jar:9.0.70]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:930) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.70.jar:9.0.70]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.70.jar:9.0.70]
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat.start(Tomcat.java:486) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.70.jar:9.0.70]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.initialize(TomcatWebServer.java:123) ~[spring-boot-2.7.7.jar:2.7.7]
    ... 18 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'relyingPartyRegistrationResolver' defined in class path resource [com/atos/config/SecurityConfig.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'relyingPartyRegistrationResolver' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'repository' defined in class path resource [com/atos/config/SecurityConfig.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.security.saml2.provider.service.registration.RelyingPartyRegistrationRepository]: Factory method 'repository' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "java.net.URL.getFile()" because the return value of "java.lang.ClassLoader.getResource(String)" is null
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:800) ~[spring-beans-5.3.24.jar:5.3.24]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:541) ~[spring-beans-5.3.24.jar:5.3.24]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1352) ~[spring-beans-5.3.24.jar:5.3.24]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1195) ~[spring-beans-5.3.24.jar:5.3.24]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:582) ~[spring-beans-5.3.24.jar:5.3.24]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.24.jar:5.3.24]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.24.jar:5.3.24]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.24.jar:5.3.24]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.24.jar:5.3.24]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.24.jar:5.3.24]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276) ~[spring-beans-5.3.24.jar:5.3.24]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1391) ~[spring-beans-5.3.24.jar:5.3.24]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1311) ~[spring-beans-5.3.24.jar:5.3.24]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:887) ~[spring-beans-5.3.24.jar:5.3.24]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:791) ~[spring-beans-5.3.24.jar:5.3.24]
    ... 58 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'repository' defined in class path resource [com/atos/config/SecurityConfig.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.security.saml2.provider.service.registration.RelyingPartyRegistrationRepository]: Factory method 'repository' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "java.net.URL.getFile()" because the return value of "java.lang.ClassLoader.getResource(String)" is null
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:658) ~[spring-beans-5.3.24.jar:5.3.24]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:486) ~[spring-beans-5.3.24.jar:5.3.24]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1352) ~[spring-beans-5.3.24.jar:5.3.24]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1195) ~[spring-beans-5.3.24.jar:5.3.24]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:582) ~[spring-beans-5.3.24.jar:5.3.24]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.24.jar:5.3.24]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.24.jar:5.3.24]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.24.jar:5.3.24]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.24.jar:5.3.24]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.24.jar:5.3.24]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276) ~[spring-beans-5.3.24.jar:5.3.24]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1391) ~[spring-beans-5.3.24.jar:5.3.24]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1311) ~[spring-beans-5.3.24.jar:5.3.24]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:887) ~[spring-beans-5.3.24.jar:5.3.24]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:791) ~[spring-beans-5.3.24.jar:5.3.24]
    ... 72 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.security.saml2.provider.service.registration.RelyingPartyRegistrationRepository]: Factory method 'repository' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "java.net.URL.getFile()" because the return value of "java.lang.ClassLoader.getResource(String)" is null
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185) ~[spring-beans-5.3.24.jar:5.3.24]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:653) ~[spring-beans-5.3.24.jar:5.3.24]
    ... 86 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "java.net.URL.getFile()" because the return value of "java.lang.ClassLoader.getResource(String)" is null
    at com.atos.config.SecurityConfig.repository(SecurityConfig.java:64) ~[main/:na]
    at com.atos.config.SecurityConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$605b27de.CGLIB$repository$1(<generated>) ~[main/:na]
    at com.atos.config.SecurityConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$605b27de$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$66e06ba2.invoke(<generated>) ~[main/:na]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:244) ~[spring-core-5.3.24.jar:5.3.24]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:331) ~[spring-context-5.3.24.jar:5.3.24]
    at com.atos.config.SecurityConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$605b27de.repository(<generated>) ~[main/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154) ~[spring-beans-5.3.24.jar:5.3.24]
    ... 87 common frames omitted


Process finished with exit code 0
```

Spring Security + Saml Config

```
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig {

    @Bean
    SecurityFilterChain app(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        // @formatter:off
        http
                .authorizeHttpRequests((authorize) -> authorize
                        .anyRequest().authenticated()
                )
                .saml2Login(Customizer.withDefaults())
                .saml2Logout(Customizer.withDefaults());
        // @formatter:on

        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    RelyingPartyRegistrationResolver relyingPartyRegistrationResolver(
            RelyingPartyRegistrationRepository registrations) {
        return new DefaultRelyingPartyRegistrationResolver((id) -> registrations.findByRegistrationId("wac"));
    }

    @Bean
    Saml2AuthenticationTokenConverter authentication(RelyingPartyRegistrationResolver registrations) {
        return new Saml2AuthenticationTokenConverter(registrations);
    }

    @Bean
    FilterRegistrationBean<Saml2MetadataFilter> metadata(RelyingPartyRegistrationResolver registrations) {
        Saml2MetadataFilter metadata = new Saml2MetadataFilter(registrations, new OpenSamlMetadataResolver());
        FilterRegistrationBean<Saml2MetadataFilter> filter = new FilterRegistrationBean<>(metadata);
        filter.setOrder(-101);
        return filter;
    }

    @Bean
    RelyingPartyRegistrationRepository repository() throws Exception{
        ClassLoader classLoader = getClass().getClassLoader();
        File verificationKey = new File(classLoader.getResource("saml-certificate/saml.crt").getFile());
        X509Certificate certificate = X509Support.decodeCertificate(verificationKey);
        Saml2X509Credential credential= Saml2X509Credential.verification(certificate);

        RelyingPartyRegistration wac = RelyingPartyRegistrations
                .fromMetadataLocation("classpath:saml-certificate/cond2fa_256.xml")
                .registrationId("wac").assertingPartyDetails((details) -> details.verificationX509Credentials(
                        (c) -> c.add(credential)
                ).wantAuthnRequestsSigned(false))
                .singleLogoutServiceLocation("http://localhost:8080/logout/saml2/slo").build();
        return new InMemoryRelyingPartyRegistrationRepository(wac);
    }

}
```

application.properties

```
# Configure connection pooling if needed
spring.datasource.hikari.maximum-pool-size=10

#H2
spring.jpa.show-sql=false
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true
spring.h2.console.enabled=true
spring.h2.console.path=/h2-console
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=pass
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:testdb
#spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=false
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect

spring.mvc.pathmatch.matching-strategy = ANT_PATH_MATCHER
```

build.gradle

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.7.7'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.15.RELEASE'
}

group = 'com.atos'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '17'

configurations {
    compileOnly {
        extendsFrom annotationProcessor
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}


dependencies {
        implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security'
    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    developmentOnly 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.security:spring-security-test'
    implementation group: 'org.modelmapper', name: 'modelmapper', version: '3.1.1'
    implementation 'org.springframework.security:spring-security-core:6.0.1'
    implementation 'org.springframework.security:spring-security-saml2-service-provider'


    //Swagger
    implementation 'io.springfox:springfox-swagger-ui:3.0.0'
    implementation 'io.springfox:springfox-boot-starter:3.0.0'
    implementation 'io.springfox:springfox-swagger2:3.0.0'


    // H2
    runtimeOnly 'com.h2database:h2'
}

tasks.named('test') {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}

tasks.withType(Jar).all {
    duplicatesStrategy 'exclude'
}
```

Tried a bunch of dependencies suggested on stackoverflow for similar problems, changing the tomcat port, changing project jdk from 17 to 11 nothing helped. I'm still a junior dev btw.

Appreciate your feedback.

Answer (score 0):

The SAML stack can be difficult to debug!  Look at the last Exception in the stack trace:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke 
  "java.net.URL.getFile()" because the return value of 
  "java.lang.ClassLoader.getResource(String)" is null
```

Looks like an error locating `classpath:saml-certificate/cond2fa_256.xml`.

1. Check that the path `saml-certificate/cond2fa_256.xml` is spelled right.
2. Check that the file `cond2fa_256.xml` does really appear within a directory named `saml-certificate` either in your file system or in a JAR file.

   - If in your file system, `saml-certificate` should be a sub-directory of one of the entries in your CLASSPATH.
   - If in a JAR file, then `saml-certificate` should be a top-level directory in that JAR file.

Comment: already checked file paths. didn't solve anything on that regard. Weird thing is it works locally on a colleagues laptop. Pulled from Git it throws the error above on my laptop. When we deploy on our GCP server it throws the same error as on my laptop.